# Search in filtered list

Tags: excel, vba

I have a simple worksheet A containing a list of strings under the same column. Moreover, from another sheet B I have a macro that searches for the former strings in the list. Everything works fine except for the case when a filter is applied to the list in worksheet A.
In this case, the search acts like the elements filtered in the list don't exist.

Is there a way to refer to the original list without caring whether the list displayed is filtered or not?

The macro that access the list:

```
Worksheets("A").Range("A:A").Find(Cells(row, 1).value, LookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True)
```

I gave a look into [Find](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/api/excel.range.find) but I didn't find useful workarounds.

Comment: You can filter the datas using an excel query and apply the second filter on the table created by the first query

Comment: Do you need the address of the match or just the value? Just the first match or all of them?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `Application.Match()` function returns the appropriate record even in cases where it is filtered away. The syntax would be:

```
Application.Match(cells(row, 1).value, Range("A:A"), 0)
```

Instead of returning a `Range` object, it will return a `Long` pointing to the row where the data was found, or an error if it isn't found. Perhaps this can be a workaround instead of using `.Find()`

Edit to clarify: The function does not return the row number of the matched cell, but rather the row offset of the range being searched. For example, if your code is `Application.Match("ABC", Range("A5:A10"), 0)`, and the match is in the first cell of the range, `A5`, the function call returns the number 1, not 5.

Answer (score 0):

An alternative to `.Find` and `.Match` is the classic cell by cell comparision:

```
lr = Range("a111111").End(xlUp).Row

For i = 1 To lr
    If Cells(i, 1) = <reference value> Then 
         <match found>
    End If
Next
```

This is a perfect alternative to `.Find` with `LookIn:=xlValues, lookAt:=xlWhole, MatchCase:=True`. It will check all cells in column A including hidden and filtered out cells. You will not even experience a slowdown under a few thousand rows.

Comment: actually lr is set on the row of the greatest element remaining after filter application so does not seems to work.

Comment: You can then try with `Usedrange`: replace the `For` line with `For i = ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row To ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Row + ActiveSheet.UsedRange.Rows.Count - 1`. Not to mention that `ActiveSheet` stands for better understanding and its usage is to be avoided especially when the users can access/change the active workbooks interactively.